# How to launch activity on BroadcastReceiver when boot complete on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I use below code to let my app can be auto-launch after boot complete 10 seconds:

```
public class BootActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";   

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
        if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context,    
                    BootActivity.class));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                Intent newAct = new Intent();
                newAct.setClass(BootActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity( newAct );
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

But the `setClass` and `startActivity` cannot use here.
How can I modify to set it to launch activity?

Comment: `But the setClass and startActivity cannot use here.` means?

Comment: It cannot find these 2 methods.

Comment: The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type BootActivity

Comment: Try context.startActivity( newAct);

Comment: Make final of context and use the context.startActivity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May this help you...

Create class called `AutoStart.class`

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
                Intent i = new Intent(context, SochActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
    }
```

**Manifest file:**

under manifest tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Under application tag:

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".AutoStart"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="500" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Do I also have to add this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

to the Manifest?

Comment: Yes. You have to add <uses-permission/>

Answer (score 4):

Try this in manifest file,

```
<receiver android:name=".BootActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Make sure also to include the completed boot permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```