# Android lock screen : activity started first when mobile on

Tags: android, locking, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen

I develop one apps mobile number lock, i want whenever mobile on,or restart or switch on ,or on from the top/left/right button placed on mobile in short whenever mobile screen on my lock activity call, i have no idea to how to call activity at time of mobile on please any one give some related example to start activity at first when mobile on. so my lock dispay to user and then enter number password and lock open ...thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is working for me :

```
enter code here :
    public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (intent.getAction() != null) {
           if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Intent s = new  Intent(context,ViewPagerMainActivity.class);
            s.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(s);
            }
       }
    }
}

 and in menifist file add follwing:

enter code here :
<receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
        <intent-filter android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, to achieve this. One way is you can go through Broadcasting a message for your app, after the boot of your mobile. Try reading:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Also have look at this thread, this will solve your problem.
[How to launch activity on BroadcastReceiver when boot complete on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542286/how-to-launch-activity-on-broadcastreceiver-when-boot-complete-on-android)

Comment: thanks for answers,i done using broadcast receiver but my problem is that it work only when my mobile boot/restart but i also want to when i simply on/off mobile or after locked it activity display, and ya i got automatic dialog-wallpaper when simply on/off

Comment: Can you explain how is on/off mobile different from boot/restart mobile?

Comment: mobile automatically-locked or locked by us = off then we locked on or start mobile after off that mobile on

Comment: means when mobile locked then user try to lock on at that time i want to display my own lock (my lock activity )instead of mobile default lock.

Comment: i want to exact ask by this user please see this link and answers quickly thank in advance :     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026308/android-display-own-lock-instead-of-default-when-screen-on-off

Comment: As I said before, Broadcast Receiver is the way to utilize system Intents. If you went through the link that I shared you would've grasped with its usage and examples. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html