# Android: start activity on boot complete

Tags: java, android, startup, boot

I have tried this on a few android phones with no luck (i did start the app once).

This was mostly generated from android studio 1.3.2 and from some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611048/start-activity-on-boot) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542286/how-to-launch-activity-on-broadcastreceiver-when-boot-complete-on-android) and the [other](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-start-an-application-at-device-bootup-in-android).

Perhaps someone can point out what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

edit: moved receiver inside app, but no joy.

edit2: added missing permissions for receiver. now seems to work on a nexus 4. but not on the kindle fire or the at&t tablets. although it seems to come right away if i press the circle icon on the azpen.

edit3: seems to work sometimes on the fires now.

```
package acme.startup;
import android.content.*;
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
}

package acme.startup;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_settings)
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="acme.startup" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:label="BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Register `receiver` inside `<application>` tag

Comment: did that and added permission. nexus 4 works, the others do not :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `Component` must be declared inside `application` tag into `manifest`. Here you declared `receiver` outside of `application` tag. Read [**`Structure of the Manifest File`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct).

---

Correct manifest wil be

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="acme.startup" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:label="BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add permission to manifest file. Add this before your `<application>` tag :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: i forgot to copy that over :(